# What does "Surprising shading" mean in this review of Glass Onion

Tags: word-meaning

[In RogerEbert.com's review of Glass onion](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery-2022), there's this sentence:

> His guests include Hudson’s model-turned-influencer Birdie, who keeps getting into trouble for tweets she doesn’t realize are racist; Hahn’s married mom and no-nonsense politician Claire; Dave Bautista’s brash men’s-rights YouTuber Duke Cody and his scantily clad girlfriend, Whiskey (Madelyn Cline, **finding surprising shading**); and Odom’s beleaguered scientist, Lionel, who endures urgent faxes from Miles at all hours of the day and night. Also receiving an unexpected invitation is the jovial and fashionable Benoit Blanc, who welcomes the fun of this challenge, as he seems at sea between cases.

I've never seen that verbiage before. My best guess is that it means she has more character depth than would be expected, but I've never seen "shading" used in that context. Does anybody have other examples of "shading" being used in this manner?

Comment: Better, presumably, than merely 'sketching' the character [in outline?]' (another acting metaphor borrowed from drawing) 'Both actors do a fine job of shading in their characters, but there's only so much they can do. People sometimes complain when a critic ...'  https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/on-chesil-beach-2018

Comment: Google `Roger Ebert "shading" review`. he seemed fond of the usage.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Crumbs! I'd say Ebert is *inordinately* fond of this somewhat obscure usage! Personally, I think it's pretentious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - he is not alone.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, I guess *all* "art" critics tend towards pretentiousness. But like Robin here, "I've never seen that verbiage before". And for the last 10 years I've probably watched an average of 2 movies a night, preceded and/or followed by reading several reviews. Ebrert may not be "alone", but I'd say he's in a very select group whose (domain-specific?) metaphoric vocabulary probably isn't relevant to even many native Anglophones, let alone *learners*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've got to agree, and I think it's lazy writing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Me, I'm a bit surprised by the ***surprising*** characterisation. Madelyn Cline has a pretty solid background. She had a relatively minor role in wildly successful *Stranger Things*, which exposure was presumably responsible for her getting top billing in the not-unsuccessful *Outer Banks*. Perhaps Ebert is implying "TV series exposure" (usually mere entertainment) is less important than actual *movies* (potentially "works of art").

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it should be mentioned that the famous film critic Roger Ebert was born in 1942 and died in 2013. His web site lives on, and that November 2022 review of _Glass Onion_ is credited to 'Christy Lemire'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A drawing that is 'shaded' well uses varying amounts of pigment to give an illusion of depth. Critics of theatre, film, and TV seem fond of using metaphors derived from drawing or painting to discuss aspects of actors', scriptwriters', or directors' creation or portrayal of characters.

> Slotnick and Hargreaves, both underrated character actors, portray
> them with **a rich, nuanced shading** that elevates the film.

(Paywalled) 2022 [New York Times review](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/27/movies/they-them-us-review.html) of '*They/Them/Us* a dramatic comedy about two divorced 40-somethings wading into B.D.S.M.'

> [Woody] Harrelson plays Dave Brown, a blustery cop and Vietnam vet
> who, when he isn’t humiliating female colleagues and behaving
> violently toward suspects, listens to a lot of right-wing radio and
> chills at home in a rather unorthodox living situation: He
> co-habitates with two sisters (Cynthia Nixon and Anne Heche) with whom
> he’s had two daughters. That this brute can be a pushover in a house
> full of females seems at first like **a redemptive bit of character
> shading**, but it’s soon clear that the fortress Brown imagines his home
> life to be is as much a myth as the steely professional exterior he
> tries to cultivate.

2011 [Vulture.com review](https://www.vulture.com/2011/11/movie-review-woody-harrelson-anchors-the-feverish-rampart.html) of *Rampart* (police drama film)

> I do wish the film had offered **some real character shading**: As Diego,
> Castillo basically has two speeds: tense and intense. We don’t see
> much of Pedro at all, so despite our hero’s rage at the loss of his
> twin, the hurt never quite comes through for us.

2019 [Vulture.com review](https://www.vulture.com/2019/05/el-chicano-2019-review.html) of 'El Chicano' (film)

> This horror-action picture offers modest genre pleasures and a
> consistently spooky vibe, resulting in a film that has been designed
> chiefly to ensure future sequels, although the story includes **enough
> emotional shading** and robust set pieces to be an engaging standalone
> feature.

2022 [Screen Daily review](https://www.screendaily.com/reviews/morbius-review/5168975.article) of *Morbius* (horror film)

> Well intentioned but painfully twee, the indie road trip comedy
> “Better Start Running” aims to tell the story of two young dreamers on
> the run from the law but gets bogged down in quirkiness, early and
> often. An accomplished cast does what it can to bring the material to
> life, but it’s tough to add **fine emotional shading** to characters so
> thick and cartoonish.

2018 [*LA Times*](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-capsule-better-start-running-review-20181011-story.html) review of *Better Start Running* (a comedy film)

Comment: Excellent answer! My only suggestion is to bold instances of "shading" in the examples to make them easier to spot.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That would encourage skim-reading.

Comment: Yes, as I like to do! :)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - however...